# Hide Price and Add to Cart button in Quick View of 3rd Party Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress/WooCommerce site. I am trying to create a catalog, members-only site where you have to be logged in to see pricing. I am currently using the plugin WooCommerce Catalog Visibility Options which works great for the typical WooCommerce pages.

However, I am also using the plugin Woocomerce Image Mapper which lets me tag diagrams/layouts with links to products. This link is in the form of a Quick View popup which is still showing the pricing and add to cart buttons. Is there a code snippet I can add to the mapper plugin to hide the pricing unless a customer is logged in?

Side note, I took html, css, some javascript and some php classes in college. I am still very novice with php, but slowly trying to learn.

Comment: Is there any documentation of Woocomerce Image Mapper?

Comment: My apologies, what do you mean by documentation? Sample code? Licensing?

Comment: Apparently, source code of this plugin isn't public, so it hard to suggest something. 
You can try to add to your function.php 
`$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ($user->exists()) {
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 20);
}`
However, it will remove all add to cart button for loged in users,

Comment: What sample code section do you need from Mapper? I can post it here. I have already gotten rid of the cart in the regular shopping area, it is specifically what this plugin pulls up that is still showing. It's a quick view that is still showing the pricing.